# boost/interprocess/detail/tmp_dir_helpers.hpp no longer present in boost since 1.56

Tags: c++, boost

I have some legacy code that uses

```
boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::create_tmp_and_clean_old
```

to reinitialize boost::message_queue on program start. Up until boost 1.56 this function was located in

```
boost/interprocess/detail/tmp_dir_helpers.hpp
```

but once I upgraded to 1.57 I realized that the whole header just up an vanished... 
Can someone tell me the correct way of handling this?  Is there some new function/mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here, clearly, is that one should never use the undocumented parts of a library. Those are ***not*** part of the API.

In this particular case it's especially visible in the filenames (`detail`) and namespace names (`ipcdetail`). But this is only bonus: in general library writers are not "required" to provide such hints.

So, no there is no "new function/mechanism", in fact there is not even a breaking change (in all likelihood this "change" is therefore not reported in the release notes).

---

### Boost 1_55 implementation

What did `create_tmp_and_clean_old` do?

```
inline void create_tmp_and_clean_old(std::string &tmp_name)
{
//First get the temp directory
std::string root_tmp_name;
get_tmp_base_dir(root_tmp_name);

//If fails, check that it's because already exists
if(!create_directory(root_tmp_name.c_str())){
    error_info info(system_error_code());
    if(info.get_error_code() != already_exists_error){
        throw interprocess_exception(info);
    }
}

#if defined(BOOST_INTERPROCESS_HAS_KERNEL_BOOTTIME)
    tmp_folder(tmp_name);

    //If fails, check that it's because already exists
    if(!create_directory(tmp_name.c_str())){
        error_info info(system_error_code());
        if(info.get_error_code() != already_exists_error){
            throw interprocess_exception(info);
        }
    }
    //Now erase all old directories created in the previous boot sessions
    std::string subdir = tmp_name;
    subdir.erase(0, root_tmp_name.size()+1);
    delete_subdirectories(root_tmp_name, subdir.c_str());
#else
    tmp_name = root_tmp_name;
#endif
}
```

> ***This is only internally used in Windows interprocess mechanisms (`semaphore`, `mutex`, `mapped_region`) indirectly through `*_intermodule_singleton`.***

### How to fix?

You could look at the implementation of the intermodule_singleton classes to see how they achieve their goal in 1_56+.

Ideally you could take a loooooooooooong hard look at why your program even needs to interfere with the library implementation detail at this level (hint: likely it's not needed/could better be achieved some other way).

It looks like the `create_shared_dir_and_clean_old` function still exists in `boost/interprocess/detail/shared_dir_helpers.hpp`

Comment: Yes, it is quite possible that I do not need this in my code, but message_queue is not quite well documented and I slapped the solution for the task "just use the simplest and quickest way to do this we don't have time" from some guide into code a couple years ago and it was working ever since XD It does not make the practice less evil but reimplementing is still impeded by time.

Comment: @Zeks depends on /what/ is needing to be "reimplemented". Since Boost Interprocess has stil got all its features, it shouldn't be too hard. Perhaps, if you get stuck, you can enlist for help with that particular task on SO